# "No more", "no longer", "not anymore"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, negative-polarity-items

> You love me no more.
>
> You no longer love me.
>
> You don't love me anymore.

How are these three sentences different from one another? I use *not anymore* more often than the others. But once I used *I use your service no more* and an English guy standing by burst into laughter.

Answer (score 10):

- "You don't love me anymore" is the most natural and common way to say this.
- "You no longer love me" is grammatically fine, but sounds a bit formal and stiff. It *might* be used in writing, but probably not in speech.
- "You love me no more" sounds very old-fashioned. You'll find sentences like this in classic literature--especially poetry--but not often in conversation.

That's why the English guy laughed. What you said wasn't *wrong*; it just seems very old-fashioned and stuffy, when it sounds like the effect you were going for was forceful and angry (I'm assuming you said "I use your service no more" because of some sort of problem with the service you had received). There may also have been a discrepancy between your tone of voice and the way the English guy perceived your words, which he found funny.

Comment: I feel like someone saying "you love me no more!" should subsequently faint onto a chaise.

Answer (score 0):

What about the case of "someone does**n't** live here **any longer**"? '**not** ~ **any more**' would be strange when time/duration is referred to (as if 'no more days' is to be meant - a strange thought).

Compare with an example of "the children promised not to quarrel any more". It is not of duration, but of frequency, hence 'any more' is correct.